# http 404 error report tomcat eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm really new to web app and this is my first time using tomcat. I keep getting this message when try to run index.jsp.

[image: screenshot]

I'm using eclipse indigo, with tomcat 6.0 (Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost already started and synchronized). I've already copied ROOT folder to wtpwebapp, checked `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />` in server.xml file, but nothing seems work.

Here's the server configuration:
[image]

I just started index.jsp with this:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Hello World!
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>ChatBot</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

I wonder what's wrong...Thanks in advance.

Comment: What link are you using ? I mean the name of the project

Comment: @sheldonCooper the name's ChatBot and the link's http://localhost:8080/ChatBot/index.jsp

Answer (score 2):

First of all i want to know which frame work r u using. If u r working on struts 2 just try replacing ur code in web.xml with this code...

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Struts2</display-name>

 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me: Try dragging `index.jsp` to the `WebContent` directory. Then, right click `index.jsp` and click "Run on server".